# Twitter API Application Limits

Tags: twitter

Very simple question: is there a limit to how many applications a Twitter account can have? There doesn't appear to be, which is strange given the fairly stringent rate-limits

Answer (score 2):

I dont think theres a limit. I had a look around their docs and they are more limiting the apps themselves eg. the amount of times those apps pull data from twitter ect.

Have you hit limit or is this just speculation?

Comment: Nope, as I said - there don't appear to be any limits to how many applications you can create